# My pc doesnt accept New Ram

Tags: memory

Grettings!

My motherboard is GA-P55-UD3L and i bought two new ram kits for it:

1. TeamGroup Desktop RAM Value 4GB 1600MHz DDR3

(afterwards i bought another one thinking that the first was broken)

2. RAM KINGSTON HX313C9FR/4 4GB DDR3 1333MHZ HYPERX FURY RED SERIES

When is insert them my pc usually just restarts the booting screen or just showing black screen.. Any ideas?

Tried everything, resetting bios,trying every slot with one ram at a time ect.
I am in desperate need of help.

Thank you in advanvce! :D

Comment: Do you still have your original RAM?  If so, does the computer boot properly when they are inserted instead of the new ones?

Comment: yeap the pc operates fine with the old Ram 
(2x1 GB and 1x2 GB 1333mhz all of them)

Comment: Did you check if your MB can use the ram you bought?

Comment: I guess you mean my motherboard
it says it can operate with up to 16 gb of ram

Comment: The amount isn't the only thing - different MBs require different types of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Your [motherboard manufacturer](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3501) says that you can support up to 16GB, so you're not overdoing it on amount of RAM or size of individual sticks.  However, it does not support 1600MHz, so your first stick listed probably won't work.

The simplest way to check the RAM stick you bought would be to try it in another machine.  If you don't have that available, you may want to try reseating the RAM.  Seems unlikely that it would have been bad in all 4 slots, but you never know.  You should push it until you hear both side latches click, and then still press firmly a little bit more (maybe even with a bit of a wiggle).  You might also try blowing the slots out with compressed air to make sure there's no dust in them that could be fouling the connection.

Finally, you might want to check the bios version on your motherboard.  One of the earliest bios updates listed on the [manufacturer site](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3501#bios) says it was for memory enhancement.  It's possible if you are still on the original bios version that it won't accept newer RAM until you update.

Comment: Thanks!
I guess i am going for the bios update since i have tried many times the slots and also cleaned them Thanks again i will post if it worked out

Comment: Cant get the update run because it requires 32 bit system
I guess the problem is incompatibility 
60$ wasted :(

Answer (score 0):

Your Ram does not seem to be on the QVL list from Gigabyte (which may be outdated), and your board is not listed on Kingston's website and i could not find a compatibility list with TeamGroup.

I am going with it is not compatible as neither list it as compatible.

You could verify this is the case by calling Kingston, TeamGroup and Gigabyte.